# Why is GCD code crashing in drawRect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

This is inside drawRect:

```
NSString *generated = [Entry generateString];

const char *cString = (const char*)[generated UTF8String];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(cString, NULL);*/

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    Media *media = [self.entry.media objectAtIndex:i];

    UIImage *image = [media getThumbnail];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        int bottom = [JHomeViewCell yOfMessageBottomWithMessageHeight:self.cellInfo.messageHeight
                                                            withMonth:self.cellInfo.hasMonth];

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(87 + (68 * i),
                                  bottom,
                                  THUMBNAIL_SIZE.width,
                                  THUMBNAIL_SIZE.height);

        [image drawInRect:frame];
    });

});
```

Right now, it's crashing at the objectAtIndex line. It's not an invalid index. The code works fine outside of here.

EDIT: I got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'
```

EDIT 2: I put in NSLogs, the first to get the media.count. It crashed with the same error.

Comment: Get the image outside of drawRect:. You especially shouldn't be trying to spawn threads inside it. There's no way to guarantee that the context will even be that of this UIView's when the main thread code is called.

Comment: Try NSLogging at which i your code crashes and how many objects self.entry.media actually holds at the moment. And Tom Irving is very right: spawning threads in drawRect doesn't seem as a good idea at all.

Comment: Is self.entry.media a valid object when the async queue fires ?

Comment: Yeah. I think it's a core data problem. Because Entry is a core data class.

Comment: `UIView drawRect` is bad place for concurrency. You have to be sure you finished to prepare graphic context within this method. Try to init all the necessary properties before `UIView drawRect` been sent

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you're drawing outside of where you should be.   When you return from `drawRect:`, you have told the operating system that you are done.   You cannot spawn an asynchronous thread before returning from `drawRect:` and expect to be able to draw just by getting back onto the main thread, because once you return from `drawRect:` the context is destroyed.

The usual way to do this is to cache the information on a separate thread, and then call `invalidateRect:` on the areas that you need to draw, allowing your `drawRect:` method to do nothing except quickly draw and exit.

If you want to lazy-load the thumbnails, I would suggest storing a copy of the thumbnail in a private location (perhaps using NSCache and using your image identifier as the key) and then if the image exists in the cache when `drawRect:` is called, drawing the image, otherwise drawing a placeholder and using GCD to add the image to a queue for thumbnail-creation.   Inside of that dispatch queue call:

- retrieve the thumbnail
- store it in the cache
- call `invalidateRect` on the area that contains the image

If you find that it is hard to calculate the location, or you are getting your thumbnails very quickly, you can delay the invalidateRect: and have it called in a final dispatch_async at the end of your draw routine (but only if you queued thumbnails for retrieval).   This would result in a single full-area redraw, instead of multiple redraws for each area containing a single thumbnail.